# split a set of data into different category

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file which is a set of data (2000 lines) example shown below

Time,Price ($),Volume,Value ($),Condition

10/10/2013 04:57:27 PM,5.81,5000,29050.00,LT XT

10/10/2013 04:48:05 PM,5.81,62728,364449.68,SX XT

10/10/2013 04:10:33 PM,5.81,451,2620.31,

10/10/2013 04:10:33 PM,5.81,5000,29050.00,

How do i split them into chunks of each category? Example:

Volume - (whole data of volume)

Price - (whole data of price)

I understand that need to use delimiter to split but i don't know how to go about it (would need a little push on codings).
I'm using vectors to store these set of data by line.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
//#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //open file
    ifstream inFile("Course_of_sale.txt", ifstream::in);

// if can read
if (inFile.good())
{
    std::vector<string> strVector;

    //create vector 
    string line;

    //read and push to back 
    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        getline(inFile, line);
        strVector.push_back(line);
    }
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for (it = strVector.begin(); it < strVector.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    stringstream ss(line);
    string field;
    while (getline(ss, field, ','))
    {
        getline(inFile, line);
        strVector.push_back(line);
    }
    cout << "\nSize : " << strVector.capacity() << " elements \n";

}
system("Pause");
```

Currently only managed to do a read from file.(and this code is copied from SO)

Comment: Read a line from your file stream with `std::getline`; construct a `std::istringstream` with it; read comma-delimited fields from the string stream using `std::getline`; push strings onto respective vectors.  Done.

Comment: From what I can see, you are reading in the entire data file, then printing out the entire data file to console, then breaking the lines up using `getline()` with a comma as delimiter. My question to you now is, why are you saving the broken up lines, e.g. the various fields of volume, price etc. in the same place as where you stored all your data earlier on when you read it from your text file, i.e. in `strVector`?

Comment: yes.. i need to break all the lines and sort them according to Volume, Values, Price, etc in a ?location?vector?.. I think i misplaced the getline() method or smth.

Answer (score -1):

This was my attempt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct entry {
    int time;
    double price;
    int volume;
    double value;
    std::string condition;
    entry(const int ti, const double pr, const int vo, const double va, const std::string &co):
        time{ ti }, price{ pr }, volume{ vo }, value{ va }, condition{ co }
    {   }
};

std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &str, const char delim, std::vector<std::string> &ret) {
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::string tmp;
    while (std::getline(ss, tmp, delim))
        ret.push_back(tmp);
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<entry> vec;
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> str;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::vector<std::string>().swap(str);
        split(line, ',', str);
        std::string tmp{ "" };
        if (str.size() > 4)
            std::string tmp(str.at(4));
        entry e(
            std::stoi(str.at(0)),
            std::stod(str.at(1)),
            std::stoi(str.at(2)),
            std::stod(str.at(3)),
            tmp
        );
        vec.push_back(e);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It's only fault tolerant if you leave off the condition.